# How to upload a pdf file to an email in swift

Tags: swift

I wish to upload a pdf file by clicking on the upload button and key in the receiver's email then send it to he/she. Once I click on the upload button, it will prompt out the pdf file content to do checking before send it to the receiver. How can I code with it?

```
@objc func sendMail() {
    if( MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() )

    {
        print("Can send email.")

        let mailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self

        //Set to recipients
        mailComposer.setToRecipients(["yakupad@yandex.com"])

        //Set the subject
        mailComposer.setSubject("email with document pdf")

        //set mail body
        mailComposer.setMessageBody("This is what they sound like.", isHTML: true)
        let pathPDF = "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())contract.pdf"
        if let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathPDF)
        {
            print("File data loaded.")
            mailComposer.addAttachmentData(fileData as Data, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: "contract.pdf")
        }

        //this will compose and present mail to user
        self.present(mailComposer, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        print("email is not supported")
    }

    func mailComposeController(_ didFinishWithcontroller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?)
    {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

}

Comment: It’s unclear what your issue is. What problem are you having with the code you posted?

Comment: 1) I wish to key in the email of receiver by myself. 2)Upload the pdf file from my computer location.

Comment: @DanielTan Why couldn't you store the emails of the receiver in a variable and pass the array in `setToRecipients`?

Comment: Make sure the temporary file still exist before trying to upload it

Answer (score 0):

with this example i could share a pdf, first you can see it, I mean, you should push button "create a pdf" and then you can share it with email or whatever

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
documentsURL.appendPathComponent("recibo.pdf")
do {
    try convertedData.write(to: documentsURL)
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let docsurl = try! fileManager.url(for:.documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let documentoPath =  docsurl.appendingPathComponent("recibo.pdf")
    let pdfData = NSData(contentsOf: documentoPath)
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [pdfData!], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.view
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.present(activityViewController, animated: true) {() -> Void in }
} catch {
    print("the pdf can't be created")
}
```

you can custom the activity view controller for email variables